# How can I delay this Javascript code at page load?

Tags: javascript

I want to delay this typing effect after the page loads instead of starting in immediately, how could I do this?

```
document.addEventListener ('DOMContentLoaded',function(event) {

  var dataText = ["This is a typing effect"];

  function typeWriter(text, i, fnCallback) {
    if (i < (text.length)) {
      document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = text.substring(0, i+1) +'<span aria-hidden="true"></span>';
      setTimeout(function() {
        typeWriter(text, i + 1, fnCallback)
      }, 75);
    }
    else if (typeof fnCallback == 'function') {
    }
  }
  function StartTextAnimation(i) {
    if (typeof dataText[i] == 'undefined'){
      setTimeout(function() {
        StartTextAnimation(0);
      }, 20000);
    }
    if (i < dataText[i].length) {
      typeWriter(dataText[i], 0, function(){
        StartTextAnimation(i + 1);
      });
    }
  }
  StartTextAnimation(0);
});
```

Comment: Could you edit it in my code? I only use JS for this animation on my HTML page, I have 0 experience with JS

Comment: Change the `, 75` (which is a delay of only 75 milliseconds) to a larger value (1 second = 1000 milliseconds).

Comment: @ScottMarcus Changing the 75 timeout will only make the typing slower, no?

Comment: @mason um no ?! If you can't code yourself you should either learn to do so or you need to hire someone.

Comment: I changed it to 1 and 2 but both will cause the text to stop animating

Comment: 1 means 1 millisecond, 1000 means 1 second.

Comment: I changed it to 100 now but the text still starts when the page is loaded, I was trying to make the text animate after like 5 seconds after page load

Comment: Then change the `2000` in `StartTextAnimation` to a higher number.

Comment: But, do understand 100 is still 1/10th of a second - very fast.

Comment: I do understand but all that changing this value does is changing the speed of the typing animation, I want to start the type animation 5 seconds after the page is loaded and not immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it appears you want to delay the start of the animation by a set time *after* the page has loaded rather than delay it *until* the page has loaded. We all misunderstood this because the former is a much less common use case than the latter.

You can accomplish this by changing this piece of code:

```
    if (i < dataText[i].length) {
      typeWriter(dataText[i], 0, function(){
        StartTextAnimation(i + 1);
      });
    }
```

... into this:

```
    if (i < dataText[i].length) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        typeWriter(dataText[i], 0, function(){
          StartTextAnimation(i + 1);
        });
      }, 5000);
    }
```

... for a 5 second delay (5000 milliseconds)

Comment: Sorry, my English is not the best but this worked! and I understand the logic as well, thank you so much!

Comment: Do you maybe also know if I can extend the following opacity animation instead of going straight from 0 to 1 after 1.2 seconds? $("h2").delay(1200).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 700);

Comment: @Mason Yes, the delay is, unsurprisingly, the `1200` passed to the `delay()` method and the `700` is the duration of the animation. Change those values accordingly. Please post a new question if you need more help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Put the whole function inside a setTimeout.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function() {

setTimeout(function(){

 //do your work
}, 2000);
} );
```